# How do I change the ownership of files within current directory, sub-directories, and sub-directories of sub-directories?

Tags: files, chown

I want to make the files in the current directory, sub-directories, and sub-directories within the sub-directories.

Eg. Pretend my file structure is as follow

```
|
+-A
  + 1.file
  +-B
    + 2.file
    +-C
      + 3.file
```

I want to chown 1.file, 2.file, and 3.file, with one command.
Is there anyway I can do it? And can I go deeper with this?

Comment: Do you want to change ownership of *all* files in a directory?

Comment: To make sure: you explicitly don't want to change ownership of the directories themselves? (A vague direction might be `find . -type f ...`)

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I want to change ownership of  all the files within a directory. e.g. If my imaginary folder `A` had more files, I want to change those files too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want:

```
find . -type f  -print0 | xargs -0 -r chown <CHOWN_ARGS>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it simply in one `find` command.

First, make sure you are getting the right result that you want:

```
find ./ -type f
```

If you are satisfied with the results:

```
find ./ -type f -exec chown <user>:<group> {} \;
```